# Setting Php environment variable

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

I'm exploring a PHP project which run on Ubuntu. As I checked `phpinfo()` I can see the environment variable ENV's value: production.[image]

I don't know where that variable is stored? I have checked the file /etc/environment and /etc/profile to see if it's stored as system variable but nothing's there.

Now, i really don't know how to clear or set that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These settings are stored in php.ini file. You can find this file by typing: php --ini
Make sure you don't editing cli version of file.

Comment: The configuration is not in the file you said but your answer suggested me the way out. I have found out these configuration in /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf (or config files that php-fpm.conf included). Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry that I introduced you into confusion. However, I'm happy you found it.